# How to pass state to react frontend, after clicking email activation link

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Using ReactJS and Django REST Framework I am building an app where users can register.

Upon submitting the registration form, the user gets an email activation link. Clicking that link will redirect the user back to the front-end, to a message telling them that the email is now activated. After that it will redirect the user to the login screen.

Flow A:
Submit registration form -> user receives email activation link -> message (new tab) -> login form

*A new tab opening after clicking on the email activation link is a key aspect, since it means that I am starting over with new state.*

Now. My to complicate things, the app I am working on gives users the possibility to fill a shopping cart. They can then request a quote.

Flow B:
Shopping cart -> user clicks "request quote" -> quote overview/confirmation

Users need to be logged in to request a quote. When they click to request a quote but are not logged in, they will get the option to log in or to register.

Flow C:
Shopping cart -> user clicks "request quote" -> page asking user to log in or register

When they choose the registration option, they will be redirected to the registration page, and they will take the registration flow I described earlier.

Now, what I want to achieve is to redirect the user to the quote overview/confirmation page, after the registration process.  This is the page where they would end up in flow B.

But the problem is that I lose all state, since a new tab is opened.

So, my guess is that the way to deal with this situation is to store the necessary state of the front-end on the backend. Using sessions for example.

My question is:
**Are there any design patterns regarding this (type of) situation?**

I can solve this problem, but I want to solve it in a clean, proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can persist things that you want to survive a full page reload or opening a new tab inside IndexDB, LocalStorage or a Cookie, and just read that info when the app is mounted again and prepopulate state from it.

*NOTE: IndexDB is the most advanced solution, worst based on browser support, LS works in all modern browsers, Cookies will work anywhere.*

I would definitively use this method for storing things that need to survive a full page reload or opening a new tab (which basically reloads the app from scratch) for **Anonymous users** (e.g. not logged in or registered).

For example, in case user clicks on the e-mail activation link, which leads to a route that can for example be: `/registration/:token`

You will mount a component that will show the message to the user as "You have successfully confirmed your e-mail" and redirect them to the Login page. However, you can prepopulate the state with the cart info from one of the solutions mentioned above.

After user successfully logs in, you can check in the state then if cart is empty, and do a default redirect (Homepage, User Profile or Admin dashboard for example), or if there is anything in the cart reducer, you can redirect the user to quote overview directly.